What would be the human population if all humans and human activity disappeared from the mainland continents
Basically, I'm in a collaborative project where all of humanity and human-built development disappear on the mainland continents (Africa, Eurasia, Australia, and the Americas) ; and the islands have to fend for themselves in this new world. By human-built development I mean everything, the continents would revert to a stage as if humanity never existed. No domesticated crops, untouched wilderness, etc.
This would leave around 700 million to a billion people alive. All islands Greenland and below would survive, and everyone in the seas would also survive.
The biggest debate that's come up, is the population of the new world. It's been proposed that by the 2200s, the world population would somehow balloon up to 4 billion. A resettled Paris would have a population of 20 million (!) and London would have a population of 15 million.
Are these numbers too high? Most island nations have low fertility rates; the sudden economic collapse would cause less children; and automation technologies would slowly replace human labor. I assumed that 4 billion would be the population of our world by 2200, let alone a world where 90% of the population vanishes. Would a number around 500 million make more sense?

Umm, maybe you should reread wikipedia about the current world population. We are currently at way above 8 billion people on the planet. And the tendency is only upwards... Do you mean 14 billion at the 2200s maybe?

I'm certain we had a question very similar to this one, possibly identical, very recently.  As previously, the answer depends on your story - who does what when/if repopulating the continental mainlands, whether there are plagues/blights, what resources are accessible after previous mining etc.

With the People's Republic and South Korea gone, what is that "automation" that you are speaking of? And the people of Great Britain have low fertility rates because they choose to have low fertility rates, not because they physically cannot have more children. With all of nice Europe theirs for the taking, their choice might be different. VTC as asking about what is essentially a decision of the author. You want 500 million people, fine. You want 2 billion people, again fine. Your story, your choice.

@Antares please read the first sentence of the post - all of humanity on the mainland continents have disappeared.

To estimate world population you can approximate by doubling the population every 30-50 years (using the increased number from the previous year each time). If you assume a growth rate by about 3% (which is considering births and deaths). As a headstart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_time

@KerrAvon2055 Please read the last paragraph, I was referring to that. I understood that the fictitious world is down to 700m-1b initially (as of 2024 presumably). But "our world" is our real world, no?

There would quite possibly be a population collapse (on the islands) immediately following the mass disappearance, because a lot of the world's food is produced in continental locations, like the US Midwest, Ukraine, etc.  Besides catastrophic supply line disruption, there might also be severe food shortages.

@KerrAvon2055 is right. I've seen this question before, right down to the concerns about super-fast growth of world population and population centers. That makes this a duplicate... if we can find the other.

Note that this question is unanswerable without knowing the nature of the apocalypse. At a guess, Japan would be the most populated area of the "new world" and if Japan still has its technological and industrial base it would expand very rapidly into Asia. As for what the actual numbers are after ~200 years... that's an issue of narrative necessity and can't be realistically predicted. There's too much how does your story unfold? to predict that.

A note completely unrelated to answering the question, human activity over the last 10,000 years has totally reshaped the coasts of every landmass on Earth by freeing up sediment by deforestation. Your project will need to redraw all continental maps apart from anything else.

@Antares global population is just above 8 billion, not way above, and is expected to decline through the 22nd century after peaking some time close to 2100.

@JBH The most populated area would be Indonesia (population 275 million), not Japan (population 125 million).

@MikeScott Like I said, at a guess...

We've added a chatroom to hopefully help work on some questions that don't fit the usual model particularly well, if you want some further input head over to Story Tellers Corner with your question and we'll see if we can help.

Frame Challenge
Assuming that the world before the disappearance of everyone on the continents has a  similar degree of development and interdependence as our modern world economy 700 million is not the survivor pool you'll be working with. The instantaneous disappearance of the world trade network and collapse of all just-in-time deliver schedules will kill 90-98% of everyone in the world according to the New Scientist article "Why the demise of civilisation may be inevitable" from Issue 2650, and the world has gotten more interdependent since then, not less, this article is based on extensive world by the likes of Jared Diamond. So the survivor pool will, generously, be more like 70 million, scattered across the globe, not enough to maintain any shadow of modern technological society. The material culture a civilisation can maintain is limited by population density and 70 million people just don't have that.
